# Values not updating correctly in database after being operated on in a loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, while-loop, sqldatareader, sql-update

I have the following code:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Partial Class Dummy
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim r As OleDbDataReader
Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand
Dim prev_ob As New List(Of Int64)
Dim cur_ob As Integer
Dim i As Integer = 0

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=SQLOLEDB;data source=PC;initial catalog=DB1;integrated security=SSPI")
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("select single_column from table1 where date_reqd=(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()), -1),120))", con)
    con.Open()
    r = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While r.Read
        prev_ob.Add(Val(r.Item(0)))
    End While

    cmd = New OleDbCommand("select column1, column2, date_reqd from table1 where date_reqd=(select CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(),120))", con)
    r = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While r.Read
        For i As Integer = 0 To prev_ob.Count - 1
            cur_ob = Val(prev_ob(i)) + Val(r.Item(0))
            cmd1 = New OleDbCommand("update table1 set column4='" & cur_ob & "' where column2='" & r.Item(1) & "' and date_reqd='" & r.Item(2) & "'", con)
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            i += 1
            Exit For
        Next
    End While
    con.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

The problem I'm facing is that the update happens correctly only for the first of many values. All the other values are calculated and consequently, updated incorrectly in my table. I am almost certain that the looping is what is causing the problem but have been unable to find a way around it. Please help me correct it.

Comment: Are you calling Exit For without checking any condition?

Comment: @vs dev: Hello again! :) Exit For was just one of the many variations I tried to make the darned thig work. Unfortunately, I deleted all of my other variations and just pasted what I had. I had also tried a `For Each`, as `For Each obj in prev_ob` etc. etc. Didn't work. In that case, what happened was that it updated the values of all the rows with the last computed value. When I had put a `MsgBox`, it showed the right values. I go the DB and see and it had inserted the last computed value. WTF is wrong? :

Comment: It looks like this should be doable as a single UPDATE statement (are column1 and single_column the same column?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this should be a single UPDATE statement. Unfortunately, it's tricky to tell without seeing your actual table structure. First, write a select statement like this (I'm hoping date_reqd is actually a datetime column also):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1 t1a
         inner join
    table1 t1b
         on
             t1a.date_reqd = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),-1) and
             t1b.date_reqd = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),0) and
             /* You need other conditions here if there are multiple rows for the same dates
                - I'm guessing there are since you're trying to write a loop */
```

Once you have this query working, remove the first two lines (`SELECT *`), and replace them with:

```
UPDATE
    t1b
SET
    column4 = t1a.single_column + t1b.column1
```

And you should be done.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: There is only one table that has all this data. And, single_column and column1 are not the same. single_column was only to indicate that I was retrieving a single_column and inserting it into an arraylist.

Comment: @Akshay - Yes, my first query above references only a single table - but I reference it twice, so that I can join the "previous" row (obtained by referring to `table1` as `t1a`) to the "current" row (obtained by referring to `table1` as `t1b`). It's then just a matter of getting the join conditions correct. And I've written my update query based on the assumption that single_column and column1 are distinct.

Comment: @Akshay - your current queries also don't have an `ORDER BY` clause, so there's no guarantee on what order multiple rows will be delivered to you - if you could post the table structure (cut down to just the columns we're working with here), some sample data, and expected results, I may be able to write an actual tested query also.

Comment: @Akshay - it's why I recommend writing it as a select first though - so you can check that you're matching up your rows correctly.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: The order is constant and hence does not need the `ORDER BY` clause. I'll put up what I'd like to do.

Comment: @Akshay - SQL Server is allowed to return results in *any* order that it has available to it, if you don't provide an ORDER BY clause. If you're seeing a particular order currently, that is *entirely* due to good luck/fortune, rather than anything you should rely upon.

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself! :) All I needed to do was:

```
Dim i as Integer=0  

While r.Read  
    cur_ob = Val(prev_ob(i)) + Val(r.Item(0))  
    cmd1 = New OleDbCommand("update table1 set column4='" & cur_ob & "' where column2='" & r.Item(1) & "' and date_reqd='" & r.Item(2) & "'", con)  
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()  
    cur_ob = 0  
    i += 1  
End While
```

And it worked! Thanks for your answers/comments and @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I changed my primary queries to include an `ORDER BY` clause. Thanks for the tip! :)